# How to specify privacy value as Open Graph parameter when publishing to user feed?

Tags: android, facebook, facebook-graph-api

Can't seem to pass the `privacy` value correctly. I'm using this code:

```
RequestBatch requestBatch = new RequestBatch();

Bundle paramsPriv = new Bundle();
paramsPriv.putString("value", "SELF");

Bundle params = new Bundle();
params.putString("link", "http://www.some-url.com");
params.putBundle("privacy", paramsPriv);

requestBatch.add(new Request(session, "/me/feed", params, HttpMethod.POST, null));

requestBatch.executeAndWait();
```

API doc: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/reference/user/feed/#publish

The request finishes OK and the link gets published to the user feed, but the specified privacy settings (i.e. 'SELF') are not taken into account.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The privacy parameter expects a json string rather than a bundle.

Try something like:

```
params.putString("privacy", "{\"value\":\"SELF\"}");
```